# Is there any solution for University User Login Authentication for Internet access?

Tags: linux, login, authentication

To access internet in campus, students are given username and passwords.

It's needed to authenticate for every 8 hours. 
If any download in process, then the download fails. 
Need to authenticate again and again.

OS: Linux

Any commands to automate, or any suggestions?

Please find a screenshot here

[image]

P.S. It's NOT a proxy network as well.

Comment: Even if you automated your login I suspect your download will still fail.

Comment: Can you authenticate before the 8th hour?  What if you authenticate every hour, does your connection, get reset?

Comment: Can you not use a download manager which will let you continue the download if it pauses due to the network drop?

Comment: If your downloads continue to work when you re-authenticate before the 8hrs expires (i.e. you open a browser to the login page during a download -> authenticate -> download continues) then you could write a cron job and use wget to POST the page with your credentials on a regular interval (every hour?)... it's solely reliant on whether your downloads continue if you re-authenticate before the time expires

Comment: I can authenticate before the 8th hour, connection will be established without any problem. @Ramhound.

Comment: @RaghuG - So write a script that will launch your browser, which can be configured to automatically fill out the fields and submit the form ( LastPass for example ), every hour.

Comment: @BigChris yes, right. Can I use wget in a cron job for my system that runs at every boot time. Please give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I manage a small lab (NIS+NFS) network, all clients need authentication at boot time. So, the script can be kept .bashrc. Right?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No. I need to write the script yet.